# Adding "has a mobile app" popup warning to the site opened on mobile

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller

When the website I wrote is opened in the mobile browser, I want a warning at the top: Open in the mobile application.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply running through a list of devices and checking if the useragent matches anything like so:

```
function detectMob() {
    const toMatch = [
        /Android/i,
        /webOS/i,
        /iPhone/i,
        /iPad/i,
        /iPod/i,
        /BlackBerry/i,
        /Windows Phone/i
    ];
    
    return toMatch.some((toMatchItem) => {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(toMatchItem);
    });
}
```

Comment: but I want to link to google play if android and app store if ios. How will this be?

Comment: if matches with `/Android/i` navigate user to Google play
if matches with   `/webOS/i, /iPhone/i, /iPad/i, /iPod/i,` Navigate user to App store